# Chromium telling me to reinstall because I'm missing features?

Tags: update, chromium

I'm running Raspbian Buster on a P1 4B and just updated everything through the terminal (sudo apt-get update). Now Chromium is displaying a pop up that says I need to reinstall because I'm missing features.

What's up with that ?

Comment: Ignore it. It's due to the Chromium build being over 12 weeks old and will be fixed on your next `apt update && apt dist-upgrade -y` cycle (probably in March when the RPF/RPT folks have rebuilt Chromium).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore it.

It's due to the Chromium build being over 12 weeks old and will be fixed on your next `apt update && apt dist-upgrade -y` cycle (probably in March when the RPF/RPT folks have rebuilt Chromium).

Comment: Until then, see [this forum topic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=264399&start=25#p1611858) on how to disable the popup.